# Chosen: заполнить select, если в нем нет option

Tags: select, javascript

Использую Chosen для стилизации селектов, столкнулся с проблемой.
Есть данные, порядка 1000 строк, которые необходимо подгрузить в селект (по запросу пользователя), т.е. при клике по нему.

На странице имеется селект:

```
<select id="select-col" name="select-col" data-placeholder="выбрать" multiple class="chosen-select">
   <option value=""></opition>
</select>
```

При клике по нему необходимо выполнить пост запрос и загрузить в него данные. Как определить клик по select, в случае если он не содержит option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В чем сложность? Давайте разберём по частям Вами написанное:

`При клике по нему необходимо выполнить пост запрос и загрузить в него данные` - для чего ждать клик? В этом нет логики, есть два варианта:

- Заполнять `<option></option>` в шаблоне, а потом на `$(document).ready();` "инитить" Chosen;
- При загрузке страницы отправлять POST, далее "аппендить" ( `$.append();` ) данные, которые пришли в ваш `<select></select>` и уже после инитить наэтом селекте chosen.

Chosen это всего лишь оболочка над стандартным `<select>`. Если всё-таки нужно динамически менять контент внутри chosen, то меняйте его в вашем `<select>` и просто его каждый раз "переиничивайте" (я не рекомендую).

Подведя итоги:
 - контент внутри `<select></select>` должен быть заполнен до "инита" chosen;
 - если всё-таки менять динамически, тогда `$.remove();` весь блок, создаём заново `<select></select>` с нужным контентом и заново инитим chosen.

Накидал вам fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mv7xbssh/1/

Удачи!

Comment: Это то да понятно. Я просто хочу снизить запросы в базу данных. Тот контент что нужно подгрузить сейчас порядка 1000 записей, а может разрастись до 10к, поэтому не хочется делать выборку каждый раз при загрузке страницы, и тем более при формировании документа.

Дело в том что этот селект нужен лишь тогда когда к нему обращаются, попробую сделать что то вроде подложки для селекта. Ну или действительно сделать подгрузку по ссылке, это тоже вариант. Спс.